# Is the Qspatialite 6.0.8 font for SQL free text supposed to be huge?

Tags: qgis, qspatialite

A week ago I upgraded my Qspatialite plugin in QGIS 1.8, which I frequently use in parallel with Spatialite_GUI, to get the best of both Sqlite worlds.  I immediately noticed that my SQL free text entry in Qspatialite is huge, as I type.

I think I prefer larger fonts than many folks, especially when typing SQL by hand.  This font size happens to be more than large enough to suit my tastes.

Is the Qspatialite 6.0.8 tab for typing in SQL by hand supposed to be huge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qspatialite 6.0.9 reduces the font to a normal size